# Google Chrome doesn't perform POST in a Facebook Canvas Tab application

Tags: facebook, nginx, passenger, facebook-page

I believe this is a difficult question to answer.

I've configured my facebook application with the following options:

```
Page Tab URL: https://www.myapp.com.br/
Secure Page Tab URL: https://www.myapp.com.br/
```

*(both are secure urls and use HTTPS protocol)*

Browsers like Firefox and Safari are working fine, sending a POST request to the server when I open the Page Tab with http or https protocol.

However, Google Chrome performs a GET request when using facebook with http. This request doesn't contain the signed_request.

I've spent a lot of time trying to fix this and I still don't understand why this is happening. Can anyone explain and provide a solution?

**Update *(more info)***

The application was written with Ruby on Rails. It was deployed with Nginx + Passenger. The following is the configuration of the application with nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default ssl;
    server_name  www.myapp.com.br;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /my/app/rails/folder/public;

    # workaround to get rid of infinite loops while using ssl
    passenger_set_cgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;

}
```

Rails configuration is to force ssl.

Nginx access log with a Firefox request to the facebook page tab:

> 201.87.25.128 - - [25/Nov/2011:19:16:47 -0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 9693 "http://static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=4"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/6.0.2"

Nginx access log with a Google Chrome request to the facebook page tab:

> 201.87.25.128 - - [25/Nov/2011:19:19:07 -0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9678 "http://static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=4"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.2
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2"

Nginx access log with a Google Chrome request to the facebook **SECURE** page tab:

> 201.87.25.128 - - [25/Nov/2011:19:18:43 -0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 9678 "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=4"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.2
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2"

Comment: I verified from chrome developer tools that it's a POST request. However, the server receives a GET request. I've also thought this could be a server redirect, but then I realized this also doesn't make sense because the server redirect should happen to the other browsers too.

Comment: I've updated the question with relevant info. I don't think I need to paste any application code because the GET request is being received by nginx (before calling the app).

Comment: I don't think Google Chrome is innocent in this case. The problem is occurring before the rails application is called. I've also tried to remove the chrome's cache.

Comment: Hey Barbolo, any solution for that in the meanwhile, we have the same isssue. Thx in advance.

Comment: Hi, Denis. I didn't find any solution so far. I ended up using non secure pages for users who haven't activated the secure options in Facebook. Also, there are some recent news related to the topic: http://techcrunch.com/2012/11/18/facebook-https/